# Installing RVM on VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, passenger, vps

I'm just about to set up a VPS that will host multiple RoR sites. I'm planning to do this using nginx as my server and passenger for deployment. I'm wondering how I can use RVM to have multiple gemsets with multiple RoR sites, is this possible? If it is, how should I install it? I've read that it's going to be a problem when you install it with just `bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm`. I've seen it mentioned a couple of times in this article about how it won't allow multiple gemsets.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/

Any help would be very much appreciated. Any articles or tutorials on setting up RoR on VPS using nginx, passenger and rvm would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVM can be installed in 3 modes (described here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) all of them are suitable for hosting multiple rails sites with different configuration.

There is very good description for such setup here: https://rvm.io/deployment/best-practices/

For using passenger you can use this documentation https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/ - it will work nice with multiuser mode and mixed mode ... nto sure about per user installations in this case.

Answer (score -2):

I don't recommend you to use RVM to manage rails project dependencies at the production environment. It's not primarily designed to be a dependency manager, but a tool for managing multiple Ruby VMs.

A more suitable solution is using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html) which is a cleaner and safer way for managing dependencies in Ruby. Cleaner because you explicitly declare the required gems and their versions for each project. Safer, because it enforces that the correct gem versions will be loaded by the Rails application.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826379/what-does-bundler-offer-over-rvm) elaborates on the subject.

Comment: I wonder what's so absurd in my answer that it deserved a downvote, since i'm proposing a proven solution to the dependency management problem in rails.

Comment: RVM works well with Bundler and Rails, RVM was primarily designed to work on servers, your answers discourages use of RVM while it's good solution.

Comment: I'm not discouraging the use of RVM for what its name stands for: Ruby Version Management. I use it everywhere for installing/updating/switching ruby versions. What i indeed discourage is its use for isolating Rails app dependencies in a multi-tenant environment like OP seem to intend(i may have gotten it wrong) in a world where Bundler is pretty much the Rails default for such task. On my machines i just 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3', and use the default nginx/passenger configs. I don't even worry with sandboxing the site gem dependencies since bundler does it all for me.

Comment: Your answer seams suggest that RVM is bad idea on server - that is the reason of down vote. Using gemsets does not exclude using Bundler, when using current rails version(3+) you would anyway use bundler.